# How to make a player/entity glow in the dark?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way you can make players or entities glow in the dark?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when we have a problem where someone is stuck with something they're trying to get working. You get targeted answers for the specific part you're stuck, and Arqade gets more useful questions. Everybody wins!

Comment: Yeah, this definitely seems like an idle curiosity question.  If you can point to some evidence that it's actually possible, we'd be happy to try and answer it, but until then, I'm not sure how much help we'll be.

Answer (score 3):

Well, its not really glowing in the dark, but maybe you could use the `Glowing` effect (id = 24) https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion_effects
Note: This will only work in the latest snapshots and above.

This will draw an outline around the mob/player, which you can see through a wall(maybe not what you are looking for).

Comment: "Note: This will only work in the latest snapshots and above." is no longer true.